# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseCrashReporting

Tags: android

I am using sample code of parse for android ,but when try to run the code then it shows the error
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseCrashReporting`
I have already enabled the library in project properties in java build path ,please help me to find out where the problem

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }
}

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize Crash Reporting.
     ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "*****************************", "*******************");
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this);


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);


  }
}
```

and my logcat is

```
04-28 17:29:17.923: I/dalvikvm(12489): Could not find method com.parse.ParseCrashReporting.enable, referenced from method com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate
04-28 17:29:17.923: W/dalvikvm(12489): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10: Lcom/parse/ParseCrashReporting;.enable (Landroid/content/Context;)V
04-28 17:29:17.923: D/dalvikvm(12489): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
04-28 17:29:17.923: D/dalvikvm(12489): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0007 at 0x18 in Lcom/parse/starter/ParseApplication;.onCreate
04-28 17:29:17.923: D/AndroidRuntime(12489): Shutting down VM
04-28 17:29:17.923: W/dalvikvm(12489): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417f6da0)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489): Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 12489
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseCrashReporting
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:17)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
04-28 17:29:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(12489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.parse.starter"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <application
            android:name=".ParseApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
                android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

            <activity
                android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: i have enabled all libraries in java build path

Comment: at what line you are getting this error ??

Comment: at  ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

Comment: and please post the complete stacktrace, the error could come from anywhere...

Comment: please post complete [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg).

Comment: please post your manifest file too..

Comment: i have posted the logcat

Comment: please help me ,i am stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

maybe, the reason is why you are writing the same twice, I mean, you are using Parse.initialize twice...

You should to erase the second, because ParseCrashReporting must be before to initialize, but after, it is not necessary. Try it.

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new

Comment: not works ,i am using sample code of parse,it is downloaded from parse.com

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the code url you used? Maybe, we can find your error